# Index a relationship in SQLAlchemy and Almbic

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, flask-sqlalchemy, alembic

I have two tables like bellow:
Table 1:

```
class Table1(Base):
__tablename__ = "table1"

id = Column(UUID, primary_key=True)
created_at = Column(DateTime(True), nullable=False, server_default=func.now())
status_id = Column(ForeignKey("lookups.id"), index=True)

 status = relationship(
    "Lookup",
    primaryjoin="Tables.status_id == Lookup.id",
    backref="table1_statuses",
)

Table 2: 

class Lookup(Base):
__tablename__ = "lookups"

id = Column(UUID, primary_key=True)
type = Column(String(64))
value = Column(String(256))
maximum = Column(Float(53), server_default="0")
sys_period = Column(TSTZRANGE, nullable=False, index=True)
```

HOW CAN I do a full text search on `Table1` and find the status `value`. My query will look like this:

```
model = Table1
# search_term is `value` in the Lookup table

result = (session.query(model)
    .filter(model.__ts_vector__.match(search_term)).all)
```